# Plotly: Hide trace initially in pie chart

Tags: javascript, plotly

Trying this code on https://codepen.io/pen.

```js
       var data = [{   values: [19, 26, 55],   labels: ['Residential', 'Non-Residential', 'Utility'],   type: 'pie' }];

var layout = {   height: 400,   width: 500 };

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<head>  <!-- Load plotly.js into the DOM -->    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.12.1.min.js'></script> </head>

<body>  <div id='myDiv'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div> </body>
```

Question: Is there not a way to have a default of Residential as unselected trace?
I want to have all the options in the legend i.e. Utility, Non-residential and Residential. However I just want Utility and Non-Residential to be selected initially.

Comment: Question isn't very clear.

Comment: I want to have a pie chart with 2/3 values (traces) selected as a default view when I load the page. When you run the pie chart above, you would get the legend with all values selected by default. If i want to have only 2 of the legend values in the pie chart, i unselect one value. That is the interactive element that plotly provides. But how do i unselect that value by default? 
https://plotly.com/python/legend/#hiding-the-trace-initially
This should be a good example of what I'm trying to explain. Not sure how do I do this in a pie chart.